# ion-select (multiple) not working with array of objects using compareWith property

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular8, ionic5, ion-select

I am facing issue with ion-select(array objects) (multiple select).
Two items are already selected on page load, but when you open the drop-down, none of the items are checked. Here is stackblitz link to reproduce this issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-kie1wd

I am using Ionic(5.26.0) and angular(8.2.14) for my project.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Users(Multi)</ion-label>
  <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedMultipleEmployee" [compareWith]="compareFn"
    (ionChange)="multiChange()">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user">{{user.first + ' ' + user.last}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

```
compareFn(e1: User, e2: User): boolean {
    return e1 && e2 ? e1.id === e2.id : e1 === e2;
}
```

[image: How select-box looks like on page load]

[image: open multiple select issue]

Comment: did you try [value]="user.id" because user is boject not property.

Comment: yes, It works that way if we bind single id to value but I want to bind object instead of a single id

Comment: In the value field, we just pass the single value not object. like a number, boolean, etc only.

Comment: As per this documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#object-value-references , it should work.

Comment: I've faced the same issue while upgrading from ionic3 to ionic5. The same code used to work with ionic3, but now there seems to be a bug (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your `compareWith(e1, e2)` function must return `true` if `e2` is an array and a single element `e1` is in `e2`, for example:

```
// defined outside of class
const compareWith = (e1, e2) => {
    // e2 may be an array, if multiple="true"
    if (Array.isArray(e2) ) {
        return e2.indexOf(e1) !== -1;
    }
    // fallback to single element comparison
    return e1 && e2 ? e1.id === e2.id : e1 === e2;
}

class MyPage {
...
    compareFn = compareWith;
...
}
```

**Important:** also, define your function `compareWith` outside of the class, otherwise it does not work

### Background

I've had the same issue after upgrading from Ionic3 to Ionic5, and I've debugged the `ion-select` code to see what's causing this issue.

Here's the function that determines if the an option must be checked or unchecked:

```
const compareOptions = (currentValue, compareValue, compareWith) => {
    if (typeof compareWith === 'function') {
        return compareWith(currentValue, compareValue);
    }
    else if (typeof compareWith === 'string') {
        return currentValue[compareWith] === compareValue[compareWith];
    }
    else {
        return Array.isArray(compareValue) ? compareValue.includes(currentValue) : currentValue === compareValue;
    }
};
```

The `compareValue` is an array and the final `else` clause handles that case if `compareWith` is not provided. But since you provide your own `compareWith` function, then it has to be able to check if a single items belongs to that array.

Here's the actual code that worked for my specific case (comparing items by field `code`):

```
const compareWith = (f1, f2) => {
  if (Array.isArray(f2)) {
    if (!f1 || !f1.code) {
      return false;
    }
    return f2.find(val => val && val.code === f1.code);
  }
  return f1 && f2 ? f1.code === f2.code : f1 === f2;
};
```

**Update:** Added a note that `compareWith` needs to be defined outside of the class.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response but your solution is not working for me. You can check that implementation here. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-kie1wd

Comment: Please check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-i8heaq
I've moved `compareWith` function outside the `class` definition, and I've replaced `.code` with `.id` where appropriate :)

Comment: Perfect!. Thank you.